# JSP If YES then Increment

Tags: java, jsp, conditional-statements, increment

I have a set variable "vColspan" which has a value of 4

I also have two if conditionals, that if they are NOT EMPTY, I would like to them to EACH add 1 to vColSpan

Then after those two conditional have been checked, I will set the colspan of my table with the variable vColspan.

What is the proper syntax to increment a c:set variable?

Here is my code so far:

```
<c:set var="vColspan" scope="session" value="4"/>

<c:if test="${!empty vs.Data1}">
   what do I put here?                          
</c:if>

<c:if test="${!empty vl.Data2}">
    and what do I put here?                 
</c:if>

<td colspan="<c:out value="${vColspan}"/>">
```

Comment: I'm not a JSP expert or anything, but maybe `vColspan++;`?  Or if it's intermixing `<%=vColspan++;%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
<c:set var="vColspan" scope="session" value="${vColspan + 1}" />
```

Comment: Also, as seen here, you don't need the `c:out` when you're setting your td colspan: `<td colspan="${vColspan}">`